# Tweepy cursor will exit after Internet connection dropped for a few seconds

Tags: python, tweepy

Trying to get data from Twitter, I use this code:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)    
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#WorldCup -filter:retweets since:2017-6-5 lang:en', tweet_mode='extended').items():

     json.dump(tweet._json, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
     num += 1
     print "Writing to JSON tweet number : " + str(num)
```

It works well, but the problem is when the Internet connection dropped just for 10 seconds and reconnecting, it will stop and exit after 60 seconds with error:

```
Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

How can I change it to resume after reconnecting to the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code in a loop like this :

```
import time

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

while True:
    try:
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#WorldCup -filter:retweets since:2017-6-5 lang:en', tweet_mode='extended').items():
             json.dump(tweet._json, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
             num += 1
             print "Writing to JSON tweet number : " + str(num)
    except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
        print(str(e))

    time.sleep(60) # next search in 60 seconds, either it worked or not
```

Comment: if I run it into a while loop, is it possible getting duplicated data?

Comment: Usually, using this search API, you do the same search to get new tweets, so yes you can get duplicates. So the best way should be to save in memory the last tweet you got, then use it in the next search with the "since_id" parameter. See : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Comment: Nice, Could you update your answer with a sample code, please!